# Get backbone model from array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, backbone.js

Hi I have a collection response from backbonejs which is access like

`this.collection.models`

and returns an array of length 7 - each with a model inside it.

I am trying to search across this array and get the model which matches

`_id: Xmas`

But everytime I try to do it I get the error

```
Object [object Array] has no method 'get'
```

Can anyone help!?

Comment: are you applying get method on models array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this for iterating and getting value

```
_(collection.models).each(function(t){ 
                //console.log("loop Model"+t)
                t.get("title")
enter your required logic here
            }, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be working with the collection and not its inner array models, then you can use the underscore methods proxied in collection, for example:

```
var xmasModel;
xmasModel = this.collection.find(function(item) {
  return item.get("_id") == "Xmas"
})
```